# Why use GCD and blocks for HTTP downloads?

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, block, grand-central-dispatch

In a job interview, I was asked why I should use blocks and GCD instead of NSURLConnection in order to download files asyncronously. After some research I haven't found a good reason to do that. I have multiple apps where I use just NSURLConnection just fine for multiple simultaneous downloads. Is their question attempting to ascertain whether I'm conforming to whatever is trendy (GCD, blocks) or is there any actual, substantial advantage to doing async fetches in this way?
Thanks.

Comment: I could give you a reason not to. There is a limit for simultaneous connections and once you reach it, blocks will block waiting, GCD will see the CPU idle, and it will fire more blocks, which will produce even more idle blocks. I wish they gave you a more specific example of how they think you should be using blocks for downloads.

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 7, you generally should not use block-based methods to download files asynchronously. In order to support background transfers, you must use `NSURLSession` with delegate methods, and cannot use the block-based methods. Beyond that, I'm not sure what is meant here by "instead of `NSURLConnection`" in any case.

If they meant `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` (which is `NSURLConnection`), it's convenient, but much less flexible and powerful than the delegate-based `NSURLConnection`, so the only answer I would have is "because sometimes it's more convenient, and keeps the code closer together, when you don't need much flexibility."

Unless what they actually mean is the part of GCD that really does this: Dispatch I/O. There are reasons to use that directly (particularly if you're using non-HTTP protocols, or if you're managing an HTTP server rather than a client), but they're rare, and not usually for "downloading files asynchronously." The higher level APIs are preferred in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you were doing many, many connections, transferring a *ton* of data over a very fast network connection, I can perhaps see how NSURLConnection's use the runloop for I/O handling and callbacks might become problematic, if you're scheduling these NSURLConnections on the main runloop. That said, you could just as easily spool up a lower priority background thread with its own runloop to keep those operations off the main thread.

If you didn't need all the extra machinery of NSURLConnection (caching, authentication, etc), `dispatch_io*` is almost certainly a lower overhead mechanism for handling raw network I/O, but you would really be giving up quite a bit of functionality for what I expect, practically speaking, to be a *very marginal* performance improvement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure. Mainly because NSURLConnection's sendAsynchronousRequest method has a completion handler built into it which uses a block.

Maybe a trick question? To me, it seems like the interviewer just wanted to see if you could conclude that they both can serve the same function.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks and GCD aren't specifically for downloads, but they can make downloading easier. You would have to use them in conjunction with something that did the downloading (like `NSURLConnection`).

The advantage of using GCD with an `NSURLConnection` is that you can package it together nicely and don't have to rely on spread-out delegate methods. You can limit the number of connections easily too as well as pausing and stopping connections.

Answer (score 0):

My "go to" set up for complex networking is to use an `NSOperationQueue` and `NSOperation` subclasses to do the work.

Each operation then uses a `NSURLConnection` and its delegate methods to download the data and then process it.

In a way this is already using `GCD` through the `NSOperationQueue` but I can't see a reason to use any other method combining blocks and GCD etc...

Did they give you a "correct" answer?